# Error on Conversion from NVARCHAR TO ASCII

Tags: sas

I am having some issues with a table (view?) in SAS Enterprise Guide.

When running below code I get the following error:

```
DATA Dataset;
SET SAPFolder.TableOrView (KEEP=ColA ColB);
RUN;
```

**Error message:**

> ERROR: CLI cursor extended fetch error: [SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB
>   DLL][HDBODBC] General error;-10427 Conversion of parameter/column (2) 
>          from data type NVARCHAR to ASCII failed

Seemingly I get the error at arbitrary points, i.e. for several tries it might return 302,400 observations, then suddenly that number increases to 1,320,000 observations before it terminates with the error. It always terminates with the error however.

Is there some way to ignore and skip the rows that returns the error and just keep all the rest?

I have no control of neither SAP nor the underlying data, so my only solution is somehow handle the errors directly in the script and ignore the rows that have the error. It is not important to my project if I lose the rows that give the error.

Thanks!

Comment: What encoding is your SAS session using?  Look at the system option ENCODING.

Comment: @Tom SAS is not my strongest, how do I find out?

Comment: `proc options option=encoding;run;`  Also it looks like the conversion is happening inside of SAP so perhaps it is related to the driver being used to connect to SAP. Or it might even be something that is being done in the view you are querying and needs to be addressed by the owner of the data.

Comment: I get the following result `ENCODING=WLATIN1`. I am hoping it is something that can be fixed or bypassed without addressing it to the data owner as change-requests/fixes in my company is very very long for these matters.

Comment: What is your `LIBNAME SAPFolder` statement ?

Comment: So the issue is that some character in your data does not exist in the 256 characters that the single byte WLATIN1 encoding can store.  I don't know SAP but with Oracle drivers and SAS you can configure the connection so that such characters are just transferred as question marks instead of halting the transfer.  You could try running SAS with UTF-8 encoding and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: @Richard The SAPFolder is a server containing all the tables/views. I believe it is a HANA server. If I hit properties I see the following: `Server: SASApp - Engine: SASIOHNA`. Not sure if that is what you were asking?

Comment: @Tom how can I run SAS with UTF-8 encoding instead ?

Comment: I have tried following this (https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Communities-Library/Change-Encoding-using-SAS-Enterprise-Guide-Windowing-Environment/ta-p/597621) guide to change the encoding of my session, but my administrator has blocked access to that folder

Comment: Ask the administrator to tell you how to start SAS with a different encoding.  If you are running SAS form the command line it is normally done by using a different command.  `sas_u8` vs `sas_wlatin1` for example. On Windows by picking a different Icon from the Start menu.  If you are using SAS/Studio or Enterprise Guide then you just need to connect to a different application server that is using a different encoding.

Comment: @Tom I dont start SAS manually - I usually just start SAS EG and connect thru my connection profile.

Comment: Ask the admin to show you how to connect to a SAS session that is using utf-8.  If they don't have one they can make a new app server instance.

Answer (score 0):

What version of SAS Enterprise Guide are you using ?

Your SAS admin may have to modify how the server libname `SAPFolder` is set up for the workstation sessions that EG starts when it connects to a profile.  If not immediately possible you try to perform *pass through* queries that use SAP functions to either remove certain characters or filter rows (i.e. where statement) so no 'unconvertable' data reaches the SAS library engine.

If you can determine where criteria for **one** row that SAS can not convert, **and** you have an alternate SAP way to view the same row, you will gain insight on what data content is the cause and how to 'strip' it out (if that is possible).

Comment: I am using SAS EG 7.1. Unfortunately I cannot even identify one particular row where I get the error, as I cannot see the underlying data before I extract it. That is why I wondered if there is a way to just ignore the error and continue extracting all the remaining rows in the dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity, what happens if you try this?

```
DATA Dataset;
SET SAPFolder.TableOrView (KEEP=ColA ColB);
if _ERROR_ = 1 then do;
 putlog _all_;
 _ERROR_ = 0;
end;
RUN;
```

A similar pattern is sometimes used for index joins. I have no idea whether this will have any positive effect in your situation, but even if the data step still stops, it might at least show you which row it got to.

Comment: It throws the same error as earlier. I get to see the number of observations that has been read until the error `302,400`.

Comment: So it halts at the same point?

If you change the set statement to `SET SAPFolder.TableOrView (KEEP=ColA ColB firstobs=302400);` does it error out immediately or does it continue? What if you start at 302401?

Comment: Yes it then throws the error immediately saying there was 1 observation read. If I set `firstobs=302401` it gives me 0 reads - saying `Data step has been abnormally terminated`. There is ~25,000,000 rows - so potentially many errors in the entire dataset

Comment: If I set `OBS=302402` it gives me no errors, so seemingly it is not selecting the data in the same order always?

Comment: It sounds as though you can get nearly the whole dataset in two passes - one with `obs = 302399` and a second with `firstobs = 302402`. Obviously not a great solution, but maybe a temporary workaround?

Comment: After 302,402 I get "only" around 950,000 additional rows. I tried doing it so a while back, but when I hit 10+ stops before even reaching 2 mil rows I gave up.

Comment: If you get desperate, it might be possible to write a loop that works through the dataset and identifies the bad rows so that you can skip them, but it isn't a great solution.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to loop thru a dataset like that? SAS is not my strongest.